# What does { } mean before the arguments in a function call ? key_equal{}(key1, key2);

Tags: c++, typedef, using

I have been reading a C++ code that implements a Hash table. Allthough its pretty clear what the following code does, i couldnt get my head around what does the emtpy curly brackets {} do there. I tried to look it up online but couldnt find anything, most probably becase even the name of this expression is unknowm to me.

I think it has something to do with the fact that the std::equal function is typedef'ed as key_equal, but as i said i couldnt find anything related to it.

This was a part of the homework and was written by someone i do not know, so understanding the functionality is more important than discussing the necessity of doing it so, alltough i would appriciate comments about that.

Thanks in advance!

```
  using key_equal = std::equal_to<key_type>;

  bool equals(const key_type& key1, const key_type& key2) const {

     return key_equal{}(key1, key2); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key_equal{}` instantiates the type using the [braced-init-list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list%20initialization) syntax; the type then implements `operator()` with two args, and that operator is invoked.

Comment: never occoured to me that it is a class not a function and is being initialized with an empty initializer-list. Thanks

Comment: Here is more revelant link: [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list%20initialization).
It's not a `std::initializer_list` since it could have contents of different types, but a `braced-init-list`.